# Does doing a factory reset or backup restore affect the operating-system version?

Tags: 8.1, update, reset

If I get a device running an older version of WP and update it, then have a reason to do a factory reset, will it reset the phone exactly to the initial state or will the OS remain at the updated newer version?

Similarly does a phone backup include the OS version or will it just try to restore all the apps and settings on whichever OS version is currently installed on the phone?

Answer (score 3):

Doing a factory will not modify the version of your Operating System. Your OS will remain in the newer version. I know it from my personal experience. I have done factory reset on Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 10 mobile. Both the resets didnot alter my OS versions.

Restoring a backup will not change your OS version either. It will just restore the settings, your data, etc... The backup will not change your OS version.